What would the temperature of the tropics be if the atmosphere did not try to balance out heat the latitudinal surplus and deficit
The atmosphere acts to even out the heat imbalnce between the surplus at the tropics and the deficit at the poles.  Assuming that the composition and density of the atmosphere stay the same, what would happen to the temperatures at the tropics and the poles?  I am asuming that these areas would get increasingly hot or cold but by how much?

Do you mean that we are assuming that there is no convection? Or also conduction and radiation?

Or ocean currents or hurricanes or ...?
